# How can I incorporate the gradient of the outputs wrt the inputs in the loss function using Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have managed to incorporate the gradient into the loss function, but the issue is that I cannot seem to pick the specific gradient I need. The model has multiple inputs and a single output, and I am currently unsure which one is being used. The model is defined as follows:

```
input_shape = (5,)
input_tensor = Input(shape = input_shape)
l1 = Dense(400, activation = 'relu')(input_tensor)
l2 = Dense(400, activation = 'relu')(l1)
l3 = Dense(400, activation = 'relu')(l2)
l4 = Dense(400, activation = 'relu')(l3)
output_tensor = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(l4)
model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)


def custom_loss(input_tensor, output_tensor):
    def newloss(y_true, y_pred):
        mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
        gradients = K.gradients(output_tensor, input_tensor)[0][:,1]
        return mse + K.maximum(-1*gradients, 0)
    return newloss


sgd = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999)
model.compile(loss = custom_loss(input_tensor, output_tensor),
              optimizer = 'sgd',
              metrics = ['mae'])

epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
# Fit the model weights.
history = model.fit(x_train_bs, y_train_bs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test_bs, y_test_bs))
```

Based on my understanding the K.gradients function should produce 5 derivatives (due to the 5 inputs), but I am unable to index it to pick the one I need specifically. I am quite unexperienced with Keras so any help/ intuition would be much appreciated.

Comment: Choose only the input you want, instead of using all inputs in the gradient.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do but I'm unsure at which stage I'm supposed to do it. If I try to pick the input at the first stage in the custom_loss argument, it gives me an error. My current attempt at that is the gradients variable with the [0][:,1] indexing at the end, but this is not working as I would like it to.

Comment: What is the error message, exactly? What happens when you do `K.gradients(output_tensor, input_tensor[0])` instead? (that's what @DanielMöller suggests)

Comment: This is what I get with the indexing: ```InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [100] vs. [0]
  [[node gradients/loss/dense_5_loss/newloss/weighted_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at /opt/anaconda3/envs/geronimo_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_785]```

Comment: When I run the code you posted, I do not get any error (my keras version is 2.3.1). Which gradient do you need, exactly? `K.gradients(output_tensor, input_tensor)[0][:,i]` should correspond to the gradient of the output with respect to the i-th input.

Comment: I am also running keras 2.3.1 but when I run ```K.gradients(output_tensor, input_tensor[0])``` it returns the error I posted above. It makes sense to me that you would index the gradient using ```K.gradients(output_tensor, input_tensor)[0][:,1]``` in order to obtain the derivative wrt the second input (which is what I need), but if I try with values other than 1, the loss during training does not appear to change at all (even though with the third input all the derivatives are negative, so it should be returning larger loss values), but perhaps I am just not seeing it properly.